# Renaming the "themes" folder in wordpress under wp-content

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have to change the folder name "themes" which is located in wordpress under this path "htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/themes". when i change this folder name then i can not install and activate any theme. Any one can help me doing this job.

Comment: why would you want to rename the theme folder?

Comment: Because i want to hide that i am using wordpress, no one can now that this site is developed in wordpress.

Comment: Good luck! there are many ways you can find if the site is on WP. Simple method : http://www.isitwp.com/ (there are many more ways)

Answer (score 3):

That is hardcoded, so you can't change the theme folder location. But you can register an additional theme folder with

```
<?php register_theme_directory( $directory ) ?>
```

And then only use that one.

For more information, see http://codex.wordpress.org/register_theme_directory

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the theme directory, you can only change `wp-content` like this: `define('WP_CONTENT_URL','/wp-content');`

However you can create a new folder as a symlink to your theme directory.
 For example, my path was `/wp-content/themes/nextlocal/` now it's just `/content/`

To do this, open up a shell connection to your server, navigate to your Wordpress directory, and for me, the command was `ln -s wp-content/themes/nextlocal content` and if I were to explain what it's doing, `ln -s` creates the symlink, then the next parameter is the destination where your shortcut should end up, and the final parameter is what you want the name of your shortcut to be. In my case, just `/content/` is what I wanted.